# Sybase ASE fetching millions of rows is slow

Tags: sql, database, database-design, inner-join, sap-ase

A query on Sybase tables takes a long time to fetch when the returned row count is in the millions. Execution is fast with indexes, but fetch is slow. What are some ideas to improve the performance of the fetch?

The three tables are similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1{ // data
    commonCol1 varchar(50),
    table1Col1 float,
    table1Col2 varchar(50),
    table1Col3 int default 0,
    commonCol3 DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (commonCol1, commonCol3) 
}
CREATE INDEX index1 ON Table1(commonCol1, table1Col1, table1Col2, table1Col3, commonCol3)

CREATE TABLE Table2{ // dep
    commonCol2 varchar(50),
    table2Col1 int default 0,
    commonCol3 DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (commonCol2, commonCol3) 
}
CREATE INDEX index2 ON Table2(commonCol2, table2Col1, commonCol3)

CREATE TABLE Table3 { // join
    commonCol1 varchar(50),
    commonCol2 varchar(50),
    commonCol3 DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (commonCol1, commonCol2, commonCol3) 
}
CREATE INDEX index3 ON Table3(commonCol1, commonCol2, commonCol3)
```

The query is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProc @val1 varchar(50), @val2 varchar(50)
    AS BEGIN
        SELECT Table3.commonCol1, Table1.table1Col1, Table1.table1Col3 FROM Table3
        INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.commonCol1 = Table3.commonCol1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.commonCol2 = Table3.commonCol2
        WHERE Table1.table1Col2 = @val1 AND Table1.commonCol3 = CONVERT(DATE, @val2) AND Table2.commonCol3 = CONVERT(DATE, @val2) AND Table3.commonCol3 = CONVERT(DATE, @val2)
        GROUP BY Table3.commonCol1, Table1.table1Col1, Table1.table1Col3
        HAVING MIN( Table2.table2Col1 ) = 1 AND ( MAX( Table1.table1Col3 ) <=1 OR MIN( ABS ( ROUND( Table1.table1Col1, 4) ) ) > 0 )
    END
```

Comment: you should start by adding some indexes, for all joining columns and all columns in the where clause a combined index

Comment: I have indexes on joining columns, what would be the combined indexes to use?

Comment: I'm not sure that indexes are the problem because the execution is very quick, but the fetch is slow.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *`execution is fast`* ... how are you measuring this? it's also not clear how you're measuring your 'fetch' speed ... could be anything from a slow application processing the rows, a slow network connection, a disk-intensive query having to pull a large volume of data from slow disks, or .... a poor query plan ...

Comment: speaking of query plans ... anytime there's a question about performance the first thing you should do is obtain a query plan of the poorly performing query; you could also collect performance metrics (`set statistics io,time on`, `go`, `<run_query>`; also pull metrics from the MDA tables); it's not clear from what's been posted if the indexes were created before or after the tables were populated .... and if the indexes were created on empty tables were stats updated *after* the data was loaded?

Comment: it would also help to know which Sybase RDBMS product you're using (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version

Comment: additional indexes may be of benefit but that would require knowing a bit more about the data; an understanding of the relationships between the tables would also help in determining what a good join order should be (which in turn is going to help in determining if add'l indexes would be of benefit)

Comment: another possibility, especially for Sybase ASE, is the re-use of a stored proc's query plan; if each stored proc call provides input parameters that could require different query plans for best performance, then it's possible the 1st time the proc is called it generates a 'good' query plan, while a subsequent stored proc call ends up re-using the previous query plan which may actually be 'bad' for the latest set of input parameters; a simple test would be to run the proc `with recompile` to see if it generates different query plans for different sets of input parameters ...

Comment: ASE v16.0, indexes created before tables populates, Table3 is just a linkage table, execution time going by Aqua exec and fetch times, tried with jdbc and same sort of problem - iterating the resultset takes a long time with millions of results. Each call to the proc will pass in different values. I will try to get a query plan and add it here.

Comment: to rule out issues with the jdbc connection and/or front-end application you may also want to run the proc via the `isql` command line tool that comes with ASE; output could be redirected to `/dev/null` or a file, but if going to a file make sure you take into consideration any issues that could slow down writes to that file (eg, filesystem using journaling, network mounted filesystem, filesystem sitting on a RAID-5 like disk subsystem, write activity being filtered by a malware/IO validation process)